# How to append an Incrementing number to a table value in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, toad

Using Oracle, I have a procedure to create unique ID numbers. Currently the ID number is built with the sysdate year concatenated with a "-". I then update the ID number to concatenate a value from within the table after the dash.

EX: 2022-8501.

Instead of using a table value, I want to increment the number after the dash by 1, and it should start back at 1 every year.

EX: 2022-1, 2022-2, 2022-3 // (Next year) 2023-1, 2023-2, 2023-3

What would be the best way to approach this? I have attached my current code below.

```
INSERT INTO PLANE_INFO.ID_NUMBERS (PLANE_ID)
    VALUES (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')||'-')
    RETURNING ENTRY_ID INTO v_entry_id;

UPDATE PLANE_INFO.ID_NUMBERS
    SET PLANE_ID = PLANE_ID || LPAD(v_entry_id,5,'0')
    WHERE ENTRY_ID = v_entry_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way? Use a sequence.

```
create sequence seq;

insert into plane_info.id_numbers (plane_id)
values (extract (year from sysdate) ||'-'|| seq.nextval);
```

Comment: what if I want the number to reset after each year? @Littlefoot

Comment: Reset the sequence, or create a custom function which would accept year as a parameter and return sequence values for each year (you'll also need a table which stores the last fetched sequence value per year). Function should be autonomous transaction as you'll have to insert/update rows in that table.

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR] Just use a normal sequence and if you want to generate the pseudo-sequence that restarts every year then you can calculate it for **display** purposes (but you should not use it as a referential constraint).

---

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PLANE_INFO.ID_NUMBERS (
  id   NUMBER
       GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT table_name__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  year NUMBER(4)
       CONSTRAINT table_name__year__nn NOT NULL
);
```

*Note: `IDENTITY` columns are available from Oracle 12.*

Then you have an incrementing sequence (that you can use as the primary key and for any referential constraints) and a year column.

You can generate your pseudo-sequence (for display purposes, rather than as a referential constraint) using the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function and string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       YEAR
       || '-'
       || LPAD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY id), 5, '0')
         AS pseudo_seq
FROM   PLANE_INFO.ID_NUMBERS t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e2a3d498f3effb6eb1493d17898c5776)*